# Save Formatted Data In A New NotePad File

Tags: c#, winforms

I've the following data format in a NotePad file:

```
123456:
7891011:
```

So with the following code, I can replace colon from every line and get the below result:

```
var line = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\Sample.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
     var fields = line[i].Remove(30);
     MessageBox.Show(fields.ToString());

     TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("D:\\Demo.txt");

     txt.Write(line[i]);
     txt.Close();
}
```

**Output**:

```
123456
7891011
```

But when I try to save the formatted data in a new NotePad file, it only saves one data. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: [System.IO.File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [System.IO.File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unrelated: `.Remove(30);` Are you sure, it will _always_ be 30? Pro-Tip: Avoid "magic numbers". Define a constant (or configuration property), use it and document why it has exactly the value it has.

Comment: That's always fixed - 30 @Fildor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always create a new StreamWriter within the line loop and overwrite the existing data. Try:

```
var line = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\Sample.txt");
            using (TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("D:\\Demo.txt"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                {
                    var fields = line[i].Remove(30);
                    //MessageBox.Show(fields.ToString());
                    txt.Write(line[i]);

                }

                txt.Close();
            }
```